# Drawing velocity vs time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

I think that velocity vs time graph would be a straight line that connects initial velocity with time t=6s, but solutions to this problem show that velocity vs time graph is a curve that goes from initial velocity to t=6s. Why is that?

Comment: A straight line graph implies that change in position with respect to time is constant, in other words, your velocity is a constant. If the graph is curved as in this case then it means velocity changes with time, and there is an acceleration.

Comment: $v= ds/dt$ i.e. the velocity is the gradient of the curve in your graph. What happens to the gradient between $t=0$ and $t=6$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is the rate of change of the position with time or to be precise

$$v(t) = \frac{\partial s}{\partial t}$$

In the graph you can see that the position changes quickly in the beginning but changes little in the end. Hence the velocity is also initially high and low at the end.